# sed or awk command to remove lines before first occurrence of a word above a symbol

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

Original file: Word to find-> "Findme please". Symbol -> "AboveThis"

```
some unimportant text
Findme please
some unimportant text
Findme please
some unimportant text
Findme please
Important text
AboveThis
Important text
Findme please
```

Modified file:

```
Findme please
Important text
AboveThis
Important text
Findme please
```

I need command to search "Findme please" which is first occurrence above the symbol "AboveThis", then delete all the lines above that.

I tried this `awk -i inplace '/Findme please/{i++}i' file` which is removing lines till only first occurrence of the word.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
some unimportant text
Findme please
some unimportant text
Findme please
some unimportant text
Findme please
Important text
AboveThis
Important text
Findme please
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="Findme please";ORS="Findme please";print ""}/AboveThis/,0{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
Findme please
Important text
AboveThis
Important text
Findme please
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that row separator (`RS`) is `Findme please` and output row separator (`ORS`) is `Findme please`. Then I print empty string so output start with `Findme please`, then I provide line does match `AboveThis` as starting condition and `0` as ending conidtion. Latter does never hold true, so everything starting from row containing `AboveThis` onwards will be `print`ed. **Disclaimer**: Solution was tested only with example you provided. If you want to know more about `RS` or `ORS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The command is working only with outputting to terminal.
If I give awk -i inplace to modify the file, it is not working as intended.
For now, I am generating new file with '>' option.
I will mark as accepted answer once I check with correct file which is in GB.

Comment: @Daweo Super and thank you. You are right this is working with the example. If some lines are added to the example, there will be printed whereas the OP wanted the block of lines delimited by the `Findme please` surrounding the `AboveThis`

Comment: @Jayjargot I assume *delete all the lines above that* means need to remove lines only before, not after

Comment: @Daweo You are correct, that is all I wanted (delete all the lines above that), not surrounding delimit.

Answer (score 0):

How about a state machine based solution:

```
awk -i inplace '
f==1 {buf = buf RS $0}                  # state 1: the word is found
f==2 {print; next}                      # state 2: the symbol is found
/AboveThis/ {print buf; buf = ""; f=2}  # flush buf and move to state 2
/Findme please/ {buf = $0; f=1}         # refresh buf and move to or keep state 1
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions:
Use greedy .* in `sed`

```
sed -Ez 's/.*(Findme please.*Important text)/\1/' file
```

Start at the end of the file

```
tac file | awk '/Findme please/ {if (above) {print; exit} } /Important text/ {above=1} 1' | tac
```

Parse file twice

```
awk '
  NR==FNR && /Findme please/ && important==0 { start=FNR;next}
  /Important text/ {important=1}
  NR!=FNR && FNR>=start {print}
  ' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tac file | awk '{print} /AboveThis/{f=1} f && /Findme please/{exit}' | tac
Findme please
Important text
AboveThis
Important text
Findme please
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure `sed` solution could be:

```
sed '/Findme please/,$!d
     /AboveThis/!{
         /Findme please/{h;d;}
         H;d
     }
     x;G
     :a
     n;ba' file
```